# how to import Universal tween engine in IntelliJ with lib gdx

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx, android-gradle-plugin, tween

okay.. I'm trying to create a splash screen for my mobile game. im using lib gdx library to create my  game. i have a problem with importing the universal tween engine for my sprite splash. what should I do.

I've downloaded the universal tween engine and extracted it in the "libs" folder in the ios, android, core, and root of my project.. and i copied and paste these lines for each dependencies:

> project(":core") {
>
> > fileTree(dir: 'D:/game/core/libs', include: 'tween-engine-api.jar')
> >
> > > compile fileTree(dir: 'D:/game/core/libs', include: 'tween-engine-api->sources.jar')
>
> project(":desktop") {
>
> > compile fileTree(dir: 'D:/game/desktop/libs', include: 'tween-engine-api.jar')
> >
> > > compile fileTree(dir: 'D:/game/desktop/libs', include: 'tween-engine-api->sources.jar')
>
> project(":ios") {
>
> > compile fileTree(dir: 'D:/game/ios/libs', include: 'tween-engine-api.jar')
> >
> > > compile fileTree(dir: 'D:/game/ios/libs', include: 'tween-engine-api->sources.jar')
>
> project(":android") {
>
> > compile fileTree(dir: 'D:/game/android/libs', include: 'tween-engine-api.jar')
> >
> > > compile fileTree(dir: 'D:/game/android/libs', include: 'tween-engine-api->sources.jar')

the code in my  Spite accessor class :

```
   package com.game.test;

   import aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenAccessor;

   public class SpriteAccessor implements TweenAccessor{

   }
```

the error:

1. Error:(3, 33) java: package aurelienribon.tweenengine does not exist
2. Error:(5, 40) java: cannot find symbol symbol: class TweenAccessor

P.S.

Im following a video tutorial by dermetfan and I also put in th terminal these lines:

> gradlew --refresh-dependencies

Comment: You only need to add the appropriate 'compile fileTree' entries to the Core and Android project sections in your build.gradle. See https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Universal-Tween-Engine

Comment: And in your code paste, you're missing a 'compile' from the beginning of your first example fileTree entry

Comment: still does not work....

Comment: I'm not sure what to suggest, other than try following the wiki instructions to a tee, on a new, bare bones project. Those instructions work absolutely fine for me, in existing projects and on a new one I've just tested.

Comment: nothing works for me.. this sucks

Comment: Did you try starting with a fresh, blank project, created by gdx-setup.jar?

Comment: ill try not using the tween engine.. maybe next time.. ive wasted too much time for this import thing

Answer (score 0):

LibGdx uses gradle for dependency management.

You can inject dependency from repository.
add these lines in your core module of root build.gradle file.

```
repositories {
  maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

compile 'com.github.arcnor:universal-tween-engine:6.3.4'
compile 'com.github.arcnor:universal-tween-engine:6.3.4:sources'
```